# Automatic height with div and with other divs

Tags: html, resize, height

For the past few weeks, I've been trying to get a dynamic result:

I have a `<div class="left-panel">` that contains other `<div>`s, and I would like the boss div (`left-panel`) to be flexible. I want it to adapt it's size based on the height of the visitor's screen and re-adapt the position of the other divs.

Actually, I set it height to `height: 100%;` in its class, with a hidden overflow and 380px of width.

Here's an exemple image of what I want to obtain: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p5Gi.gif

I tried using tables, it worked but I don't like setting an entire website with them, as they don't like very much CSS, and they are old now.

I hope someone can help me. Actually I want a very simple thing.

*Edit: My html and body classes' heights are set to 100%.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yep.**

I confirm that for me, the media queries "*almost*" did the trick.

Actually, for all common resolutions (from 1680x1050 to 800x600) I set the correct size in % for the panel in the media query rule, so as soon as the client screen is let's say 1152x864, the following rule will start:

```
@media all and (max-height: 739px)
{
.panel
{
    height: 93.9%;
    width: 380px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.50);
}
}
```

*(Only for the height size of the window)*

I say "*almost*" because the client will have to scroll the page sometimes, especially when he resizes the window manually.

I can use `overflow: hidden;`, but the technically the `<div>`s would have the same size problems :-).

Anyways, that's not too visible, I'll try other things later.

Thanks to responders though!

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to use %, for the body to change the height automaticly with the height of the resolution.

**css:**

```
.panel{ height:100%; width:380px;}

.logo-container { height: 25%; width:100%; } 
.body-container { height: 50%; width:100%; } 
.footer-container { height: 25%; width:100%; }
```

Your header and footer are the same height.. en the body has a bigger height.
So you can use 25% for the header and footer en 50% for the body. *(or other %, just like you want. if you want the body to be bigger, 20% 60% 20% for example)*

You need to work with % if you want get your divs automaticly height..

Comment: I'd use `width:100%;` for the children instead of declaring px as well

Comment: It would be fixed still since the parent's width is 380px

Comment: It does seem like he wants a fixed width in his description, but in the example the width changes so you might mention that as well, haha

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.
Yeah actually I want my panel width to be fixed at 380px.
And I forgotten to say it, but I've also tried to make all my div elements have a % height, but here are the results:

http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/239182Img1.gif
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/325379Img2.gif
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/592590Img3.gif

Actually the div elements "walk over the other ones", and change of size, yeah it's normal because they are set in %, but it's too visible and ugly.

Comment: I think what I need is just the body to change of height, and have the footer div "following" it, like a ... Dog, attached to a rope.

Comment: In other words, I need my logo container and footer to have a fixed height in pixels, and the body to have a % height.
I'm actually trying with min & max height, but no results, my footer gets cut by the window (if I resize it).

Comment: It is a little bit tricky, bit you can try, giving your `.logo-container{ 200px;}` , `.body-container{height:100%;}` and `.footer-container {height:200px;}` but the content a `margin-bottom: -200px;` to delete some of the body height...

Comment: Hmmm, well, I admit that I'm having troubles understading your method, I've tried what you said, and actually the content was cut by the footer. Maybe I'm doing it wrong? Could you give an exemple?

Comment: Maybe I should use media queries, and create different CSS rules for different resolutions.